Excel Column to Count Unique Values
I have a list of names in a column in excel. The names are duplicated many times in the data. I want to create a new column that will put a 1 for each time a name first appears and 0’s after that. My goal is to have this column be a distinct count of people. So
Shelly 1
Shelly 0
Adam 1
Shelly 0
Adam 0
Chris 1
Chris 0

Tried doing some sort of IF statement but I’m lost and can’t achieve it.

Please post your effort, even if it didn't work.

Try using the following formula:


=MAP(A1:A7,LAMBDA(α,IF(SUM(N(α:A1=α))>1,0,1)))


Or,
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)>1,0,1)


Or,
=MAP(A1:A7,LAMBDA(α,IF(COUNTIF(α:A1,α)>1,0,1)))


Or, as suggested by JvdV Sir
=N(XMATCH(A1:A7,A1:A7)=ROW(A1:A7))



Thank you. That IF(CountIF one worked! <3

=N(XMATCH(A1:A7,A1:A7)=ROW(A1:A7))

Nice @JvdV, stretch it to =N(XMATCH(B4:B10,B4:B10) + MIN(ROW(B4:B10)) - 1 = ROW(B4:B10) ) to make it a bit more flexible? ;)

If your final aim is to count the number of unique items, then use this formula;
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10;A1:A10))


Why SumProduct() and not simply Sum()?

Because you can't get the correct result if you don't use sumproduct (Office2010) But, if you want to use SUM instead of SUMPRODUCT you can use this formula onl if you enter the formula as an array formula (CTRL+SHİFT+ENTER in Office2010) =SUM(1/COUNTIF(A1:A10;A1:A10))

Count Only First Unique Item
Count First
Work
=LET(data,A2:A11,yes,1,no,0,
    u,UNIQUE(data),
    ud,XMATCH(u,data),
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    tf,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(rs,ud)),
    r,IF(tf,yes,no),
    r)

Final
=LET(data,A2:A11,yes,1,no,0,
    IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
        XMATCH(UNIQUE(data),data))),yes,no))


Edit

Although the above is educational, JvdV's brilliant comment simplifies this format to the following:
=LET(data,A2:A11,yes,1,no,0,
    IF(N(XMATCH(data,data)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(data))),yes,no))


It also simplifies the 'First Running Count' (below) to the following:
=LET(data,A2:A11,no,0,
    IF(N(XMATCH(data,data)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(data))),
        XMATCH(data,UNIQUE(data)),no))



'First Running Count'
Work
=LET(data,A2:A11,no,0,
    u,UNIQUE(data),
    ud,XMATCH(u,data),
    du,XMATCH(data,u),
    rs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    tf,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(rs,ud)),
    r,IF(tf,du,no),
    r)

Final
=LET(data,A2:A11,no,0,
    u,UNIQUE(data),
    IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
        XMATCH(u,data))),XMATCH(data,u),no))

